# How to give levitation to a player when the player is holding an item in his offhand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a server and I need to make a command that gives levitation to a player when he is holding a specific item in his offhand.

I already have this working for the mainhand:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"CLOUD\"}"}}}}] run effect give LPA3227 minecraft:levitation 1 5 true
```

But I need it for the offhand.

Comment: You're always giving the effect to yourself, not whoever is holding the item. Use @s in the  effect command instead.

Comment: i now but i'm trying to do for me first

Answer (score 1):

The off-hand (which is the proper term, because left and right hand can also be switched in the skin settings) is a slot with the Slot ID of -106. So this command checks if there is a slot that has the ID -106 and your desired item in it:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"CLOUD\"}"}}}}] run effect give LPA3227 minecraft:levitation 1 5 true
```

Comment: It does for me. What error message do you get? Are you sure that you're holding an item with the name "`CLOUD`" in your off-hand? And that you're playing as the account "`LPA3227`"? You could also try simply replacing the name with `@s`, that's probably what you want anyway.

Comment: I tried with @s but didn't work. Does this command work on te version 1.15.2

Comment: Yes, it does. Are you sure that you're holding an item named "`CLOUD`" in your offhand?